# How to create a random matrix in Pure Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random

What is equivalent pure python code?

```
A = np.random.randint(2, size=(4,2))

array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 0]])
```

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could suit you.

```
from random import randint

A = [[randint(0, 1) for y in range(2)]   for x in range(4)]

print(A)
```

output:

```
>>> [[0, 0], 
     [0, 0],
     [0, 1],
     [0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need different shapes with multiple dimensions here it is the code:

```
import random

def random_matrix(c,shape):
    for i in range(len(shape)):
        if len(shape)-i>1:
            for j in range(shape[i]):
                return [random_matrix(c,shape[i+1:]) for b in range(shape[i])]
        else:
            return [random.randint(0,c-1) for v in range(shape[i])]

mat = random_matrix(2,[3,3,1])
print(mat)
print(mat[0])
```

Output:

```
[[[1], [0], [1]], [[0], [1], [0]], [[0], [1], [0]]]
[[1], [0], [1]]
```

or just as in your example:

```
mat = random_matrix(2, [4,2])
print(mat)
```

output:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```